# Could not load file or assembly 'PDFLibNet' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, pdflib

I'm running into an issue that it says pdf lib doesn't match the `.net`version I'm using.

The problem is I'm using the same version on both

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.9031; 
ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.9031;
PDF Lib: v2.0.50727;

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/bin/PDFLibNet.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8013101b). Probing terminated.
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PDFLibNet' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for some reason it was referencing the wrong one in my webservice/BIN folder after I removed the .dll file it pulled the new one and that fixed it!